# How to concurrently call multiple separate functions and get ordered results in Python's concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

Suppose I have two independent functions. I'd like to call them concurrently, using python's `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. Is there a way to call them using `Executor` and ensure they are returned in order of submission?

I understand this is possible with the `Executor.map`, but I am looking to parallelize two separate functions, and not one function with a interable input.

I have example code below, but it doesn't guarantee that `fn_a` will return first, (by design of the `wait` function).

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait
import time


def fn_a():
    t_sleep = 0.5
    print("fn_a: Wait {} seconds".format(t_sleep))
    time.sleep(t_sleep)
    ret = t_sleep * 5  # Do unique work
    return "fn_a: return {}".format(ret)


def fn_b():
    t_sleep = 1.0
    print("fn_b: Wait {} seconds".format(t_sleep))
    time.sleep(t_sleep)
    ret = t_sleep * 10  # Do unique work
    return "fn_b: return {}".format(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        futures.append(executor.submit(fn_a))
        futures.append(executor.submit(fn_b))
        complete_futures, incomplete_futures = wait(futures)
        for f in complete_futures:
            print(f.result())
```

I'm also interested in knowing if there is a way to do this with `joblib`

Answer (score 1):

Think I found a reasonable option using lambda and partials. The partials allow me to pass arguments to some functions in the parallelized iterable, but not others.

```
from functools import partial
import concurrent.futures

fns = [partial(fn_a), partial(fn_b)]
data = []
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    try:
        for result in executor.map(lambda x: x(), fns):
            data.append(result)
```

Since it is using `executor.map`, it returns in order.