# deadlock with ThreadPoolExecutor when trying to run 2 blocking functions

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, deadlock

I'm trying to run 2 different blocking functions, that utilize the same global variable `a`.

the code:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import keyboard

a = 0

def incA():
    global a
    while True:
        print(f'inc a: {a} -> {a+1}')
        a+=1
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            break
        
        
def printA():
    # a is read-only
    while True:
        print(f'print a: {a}')
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            break
        
        
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    f1 = executor.submit(incA())
    f2 = executor.submit(printA())
```

when I try to run this piece of code i get a `deadlock`.
the output:

```java
inc a: 15640 -> 15641
inc a: 15641 -> 15642
inc a: 15642 -> 15643
inc a: 15643 -> 15644
inc a: 15644 -> 15645
inc a: 15645 -> 15646
inc a: 15646 -> 15647
inc a: 15647 -> 15648
inc a: 15648 -> 15649
inc a: 15649 -> 15650
inc a: 15650 -> 15651
inc a: 15651 -> 15652
inc a: 15652 -> 15653
print a: 15653
```

how can I fix this to make my code run asynchronously, for it to have an output that looks like this:

```java
.
.
.
inc a: 15640 -> 15641
print a: 15641
inc a: 15641 -> 15642
print a: 15642
inc a: 15642 -> 15643
print a: 15643
.
.
.
```

Comment: What do you expect the value of a at the end? It will get the last value and print it?

Comment: @Dammio  i want the threads to run at the same time, meaning that  `incA` and `printA` will run at the same time. I don't expect a certain value of `a`, this program is just  for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `submit`, you're including the *parenthesis* on the functions:

```
f1 = executor.submit(incA())
f2 = executor.submit(printA())
```

So instead of passing the function object, you're **executing** the function once and passing in the result, except that `incA()` never returns, so you never actually submit anything.

Just remove the parenthesis:

```
f1 = executor.submit(incA)
f2 = executor.submit(printA)
```

Comment: Other similar approach may be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870576/how-to-concurrently-call-multiple-separate-functions-and-get-ordered-results-in